# Anyone have working example of how to call DSAPI GetStatusInDocuSignConnectFormat

Tags: c#, soap, docusignapi

Do a form app and can use API/DSAPI pretty will except for one call that is driving me crazy.

I want to get envelope data back in the connect format (or just xml would fine) and i get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> Error in the application.
```

Here's some working code with 1 call that works and then the call that fails:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(dsapiClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", auth);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

        // this call works great
        DSAPI.EnvelopeStatus status = dsapiClient.RequestStatusEx("9d6616a1-af9a-47af-b37d-1daa4f13c008");
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Subject: " + status.Subject);

        /* this line gives me the error
          An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
          Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> Error in the application.
        */
        DSAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation DEI = dsapiClient.GetStatusInDocuSignConnectFormat("9d6616a1-af9a-47af-b37d-1daa4f13c008");
        Console.WriteLine(DEI); 
    }
}
```

I also tried `api.GetStatusInDocuSignConnectFormat`, and an `HTTPrequest` style, all give same error except `api.GetStatusInDocuSignConnectFormat` which says not supported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks - Chris

Comment: this is how the code looks - somehow the post got split ?

Comment: Make sure you indent your code blocks with 4 spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting